# nonlinear least squares in R when data are a function of parameters to be estimated

Tags: r, nls

I'm currently migrating from matlab to R, and trying to find out if what I want to do is possible.

I want to estimate a non-linear model in R where the observations are US states.  The wrinkle is that one of the independent variables is a state-level index over counties, calculated using a parameter to be estimated, i.e. the model looks like this:

```
log(Y_s) = log(phi) + log(f(theta, X_cs)) + u_s
```

where Y_s is a state-level variable and X_cs is a vector containing county-level observations of a variable within the state, and f() returns a scalar value of the index calculated for the state.

So far I've tried using R's `nls` function while transforming the data as it's passed to the function.  Abstracting from the details of the index, a simpler version of the code looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

state <- c("AK", "AK", "CA", "CA", "MA", "MA", "NY", "NY")
Y <- c(3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4)
X <- c(4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7)
Sample <- data.frame(state, Y, X)

f <- function(data, theta) {
  output <- data %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise(index = mean(X**theta),
              Y = mean(Y))
}

model <- nls(Y ~ log(phi) + log(index),
             data = f(Sample, theta),
             start = list(phi = exp(3), theta = 1.052))
```

This returns an error, telling me that the gradient is singular.  My guess is it's because R can't see how the parameter `theta` should be used in the formula.

Is there a way to do this using `nls`?  I know I could define the criterion function to be minimised manually, i.e. `log(Y_s) - log(phi) - log(f(theta, X_cs))`, and use a minimisation routine to estimate the parameter values.  But I want to use the postestimation features of `nls`, like having a confidence interval for the parameter estimates.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I refuse to install that ginormous meta package. Thus, I use base R:

```
state <- c("AK", "AK", "CA", "CA", "MA", "MA", "NY", "NY")
Y <- c(3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4)
X <- c(4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7)
Sample <- data.frame(state, Y, X)

f <- function(X, state, theta) {
  ave(X, state, FUN = function(x) mean(x^theta))
}

model <- nls(Y ~ log(phi) + log(f(X, state, theta)),
             data = Sample, weights = 1/ave(X, state, FUN = length),
             start = list(phi = exp(3), theta = 1.052))
summary(model)
#Formula: Y ~ log(phi) + log(f(X, state, theta))
#
#Parameters:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#phi   2336.867   4521.510   0.517    0.624
#theta   -2.647      1.632  -1.622    0.156
#
#Residual standard error: 0.7791 on 6 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.722e-06
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland.  I just edited to question to only include the package I use in this stripped-down example, and deleted the cross-posted version of the question.  To make sure I understand how your solution works -- in calculating standard errors and things like that, the nls package thinks that `length(Y)` is the number of observations, rather than `length(unique(Y))`, am I right?

Comment: I've included the weights in case you have different numbers of data points per state. I'd try calculating bootstrap standard errors (assuming you have a sufficient amount of data) if standard errors and p-values are important for this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Is there a specific reason you would use the bootstrap, other than just the general nonlinearity?  I have observations on about 3000 counties grouped in 47 states.